# Classic Asp: Cookie corruption issue

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, corruption

There is an ASP application made to co-exist with other .net web apps. The cookies for the asp page is actually written to the client from an aspx page. So we have something like:

```
Response.Cookies("Credo")("ID") = "ido sans lum"
```

sent to the client.

The ASP page receives this cookie, but strangely gives corrupt results:

```
sID = Request.Cookies("Credo")("ID") ' this gives "idosanslum"
```

Unfortunately I don't understand why. I checked `HTTP_COOKIE` server variable in ASP, and even it said something like:

```
HTTP_COOKIE:...;Credo=ID=ido sans lum&DomainID=5&...;...
```

So I believe this means the cookie is being sent from the browser correctly, but `Request.Cookies("Credo")("ID")` is giving me wrong results.

Am I messed up with some configuration or is this a known bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a KB article on this problem at the Microsoft support site: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262444

Hope this helps.

Update:
The proposed fix from the article is to encode your cookie content. In Classic ASP I think the following will work:

```
Response.Cookies("Credo")("ID") = Server.URLEncode("ido sans lum")
```

Please give it a go and let me know what you find.

Comment: Does this mean when writing the cookie we have to escape it (from the server side)

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how this bug can be resolved according to the article.

Comment: Pretty sure Server.URLEncode will serve you better than Server.HTMLEncode in this scenario.